# projects using Java and MarkLogic

Tags: java, marklogic

I am new to MarkLogic Server and hence to have some hands on experience on MarkLogic I wished to get some help from the projects already developed using Java and MarkLogic.

On doing google search, I was unable to find suitable examples and hence I am looking forward to all of you.

Please help me.

Answer (score 3):

Have a look at the developer site for resources. This page includes links to a number of java-based projects:

http://developer.marklogic.com/code

You can connect to MarkLogic over HTTP or using XCC, a library that is similar to JDBC. Here's the guide for XCC:

http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/books/xcc.pdf

and the javadocs are here:

http://developer.marklogic.com/pubs/5.0/javadoc/index.html

Finally, there's a great archive of discussion from the developer list on MarkMail:

http://marklogic.markmail.org

Kelly

Answer (score 0):

Kelly's answer is good. Drilling into the dev site a little, try some of the interactive tutorials at http://developer.marklogic.com/try/ninja/index

If you are interested in developing a REST-ful interface, try Corona at http://developer.marklogic.com/try/corona/index

For more sample applications, http://developer.marklogic.com/code has a good list: http://developer.marklogic.com/code/boing-boing might be a good one to start with, and its code is on github.